# Application generating Error:Must Declare Scalar Variable In Web Api 2. Also, practices regarding the code in WebApi2 and debugging Controller method

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

I asked a lot in here, as I am new to MVC, WebApi and RestService.

So, I am working with an application where StoredProcedure is being called inside Controller, but getting Error :

> Must Declare Scalar Variable @empid

Code is below :

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("~/api/Login/{EmpID}/{pwd}")]
            public IHttpActionResult ValidateLoginDetails(string EmpID, string pwd)
    {


        int a=0;
        if (EmpID == null)
            EmpID = "";
        else a = Int32.Parse(EmpID);

        if (pwd == null)
            pwd = "";

        var val = new  SqlParameter()
        {ParameterName="@val",Direction=ParameterDirection.Output,SqlDbType=SqlDbType.Int};

        var e = new SqlParameter("@empid", SqlDbType.Int) ;
        e.Value = a;
        //User.Identity.Name;
        var y = new SqlParameter("@pwd", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        y.Value = pwd;

        using (var x = new DB_BgCheckEntities()) 
        {
            var retVal = x.Database.SqlQuery<IEnumerable<int>>
            ("Exec proc_Bgcheck_login @empid,@pwd,@val out", e, y, val);

           // var ret = retVal.Single();
            //foreach(var ab in retVal)
            //{
            //    Console.WriteLine(ab.ToList());
            //}
            //retVal.ToList();
            x.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Exec proc_Bgcheck_login @eid,@pwd,@val out", e, y, val);
            if ((int)val.Value == 1)
            {
                return Ok(1);
            }
            else return NotFound();

        }
        }
```

Below statement is doing my work, but I am not getting why the dbcontext is not working

> ```
>             x.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Exec proc_Bgcheck_login @eid,@pwd,@val out", e, y, val);
> ```

Stored Proc :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_Bgcheck_login
(
    @emp_no int,
    @pwd varchar(255),
    @val int output
)as
BEGIN
    SET @val=0;
    DECLARE @count int;
    SELECT @count=COUNT(*) FROM tbl_User_Login where [Emp No]=@emp_no and [Password]=@pwd;
    IF (@count = 1)
        BEGIN
            SET @val=1;
            RETURN @val;
        END
    ELSE
        RETURN @val;
END
GO
```

Few questions, I need to ask :

1. Is it good practice, to call StoredProc inside GetMethod, like I did.
2. How to implement the DTO(Data Transfer Object) for this method? I googled down, but didn't got the concept for that.
3. Debugging method inside Controller, how to do that line by line ?

> PS : For the error, I went through different sites and threads of StackOverflow, but none resolved my solution.

Comment: procedure `proc_Bgcheck_login` acceps three parameters..

Comment: yes, it accepts 3 params.
I already cross checked into my db, its working in there

Comment: are you passing them? I can see you're only passing `val` which is not part of any of the `params`

Comment: yes, I think its the correct way to do that.

Comment: so the variables `e` and `y` are of no use to you?

Comment: e and y is of no use, but I need to bind **empid** and **pwd** to SqlDbType variables, that's why I used them.

Comment: exactly,and then you're not passing those `SqlParameters`.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh : I had passed epmid and pwd, I cannot pass e and y as parameter in stored procedure it is giving runtime error:

'When executing a command, parameters must be exclusively database parameters or values.'

Answer (score 1):

The error :

> Must declare Scalar Variable @empid is resolved .

As mentioned by @amit, I haven't passed the parameters for the **@empid** and **@pwd**.

So, the correct way to pass the parameter was :

```
var retVal = dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<tbl_User_Login>
            ("Exec proc_Bgcheck_login @empid,@pwd,@val ",e,y, val).ToList();
```

Thanks.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh indeed, I was wrong, I am facing another problem, when I am trying to execute the query `var retVal = dbcontext.Database.SqlQuery<IEnumerable<int>>
                ("Exec proc_Bgcheck_login @empid,@pwd,@val out", e, y, val);` I not geting value of output parameter `@val`. Its always predefined, i.e, 0. Can you please tell me what I am missing

Comment: Do not assign any default value,also check if you actually had set it in proc.

Comment: After removing the default,still facing similar issue(now value assigned is null). And in proc, its working good, I have executed proc in sqlserver, its working fine in there, giving correct output.

Comment: `CREATE PROCEDURE proc_Bgcheck_login
 (
  @emp_no int,
  @pwd varchar(255),
  @val int output
 )
as
 BEGIN
  SET @val=0;
  DECLARE @count int;
  SELECT @count=COUNT(*) FROM tbl_User_Login where [Emp No]=@emp_no and [Password]=@pwd;
  IF (@count = 1)
   BEGIN
    SET @val=1;
    RETURN @val;
   END
  ELSE
   RETURN @val;
 END
GO`

Comment: put it in your question.

Comment: please find the changes in the question.

Comment: try `"Exec proc_Bgcheck_login @empid,@pwd, @val output",e,y,val`

Comment: still getting the same value : null. It executed for the first time, but again it start showing the **NULL** value

Comment: you're now in a position that only you can help yourself.

Comment: change `ParameterName="val"` to `ParameterName="@val"`

Comment: Oops Sorry Amit, but I already did the change, I am editing my current code in the question. Please find if it contains any error